# chef nagios monitor node outside VPC in AWS

Tags: nagios, chef

I used the chef [community cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/nagios) to setup nagios inside a VPC in AWS.  All my nodes in my chef setup are found correctly and added to nagios automatically, and the nodes that are inside the VPC with nagios are correctly being accessed and monitored; nagios can reach them through their private IP.  But I can't seem to find a way to monitor any of my nodes that are still in the same cloud (EC2) but not inside the VPC.  I need to have them monitored through the public IP, b/c nagios can't hit their private IP (the default).

About the only way I see that I could get this to work properly is to change the `cloud[provider]` so the search will know to use the public IP of these nodes.

https://github.com/schubergphilis/nagios/blob/ac84639957aec7039c12bc6875c510b32975ccb5/libraries/default.rb#L43

I'm not sure if that will have any adverse affects for me or not.  Personally, I'm not sure I'm fond of the idea.  Is there anyway that I can configure this to specify a few nodes should be monitored through their public IP?

Comment: I was not able to find a place where that `ip_to_monitor` gets called… Looks like it only uses `node.ipaddress` https://github.com/schubergphilis/nagios/blob/ac84639957aec7039c12bc6875c510b32975ccb5/libraries/nagios.rb#L288 ?

Comment: you're right... even more sad

Comment: given the complexity of the cookbook, all the rubocop-exceptions and the implementation as Ruby class inside a cookbook, it's probably very hard to  "wrap" it. I would probably fork the cookbook, change the single line to the desired logic (or implement it). Long term solution would be to contribute back to the project, maybe the owner sees your github issue and comments…